# mysql_config_editor --login-path=local not working

Tags: mysql, editor, config

I have upgraded to mysql 5.6.13 and thought I would try the new --login-path feature.

I configure with `"mysql_config_editor set --login-path=local --host=localhost --user=user --password"`

After entering the password at the prompt I see that all is there with `"mysql_config_editor print --all"`

When I do `"mysql_config_editor --login-path=local" I **always** get "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"`

If I add `"-p"` onto the end like so `"mysql_config_editor --login-path=local -p"` I am prompted to enter the password and it connects successfully...huhhh!?

Answer (score 43):

Use double quotes around the password when mysql_config_editor prompts you.  Then special characters (e.g. #) will be recognized as part of the password upon login.

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be a bug somewhere in the mysql commands. If you have a '#'-sign (confirmed) in the password or maybe some other "strange" characters (unconfirmed), the --login-path method doesn't work. Test with another password.

Answer (score 1):

Put double quotes on password. The behavior is different when there's `#` symbol and probably the `<` `>` sign.

e.g. `"F$#d32e$@<>D"`