# Pass password to mysql_config_editor using variable in shell

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, shell, variables

I have password stored in a variable $db_pwd and I want to pass it to mysql_config_editor in a shell script. I can not use config file or db_pwd environment variable.

I am doing this

```
mysql_config_editor set --login-path=local --host=localhost --user=username --password
```

(https://stackoverflow.com/a/20854048/6487831) .

What it does is ask for password "Enter Password", but I wish to supply the password using variable.

I tried this :

```
mysql_config_editor set --login-path=local --host=localhost --user=username --password $db_pwd
```

and

```
mysql_config_editor set --login-path=local --host=localhost --user=username --password | echo $db_pwd
```

and

```
echo "$db_pwd" | mysql_config_editor set --login-path=local --host=localhost --user=username --password
```

and

- `expect`. But this leads to error in case there are warnings like "This path already exists, rewrite (y/n).
- options file, but they still give me variable not found error even when I am using it as the first argument. Is options file compatible with mysql config editor?

Any way to do this? Or should I revert to using `mysql` instead of mysql_config_editor?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22513843/1497139

Comment: along with the answer @WolfgangFahl linked to, you can use `--skip-warn` to skip the override existing name warning

Answer (score 8):

I found the other suggested answer did not work when there was no TTY. So I used this bash script that works in places like Terraform/ssh that doesn't have a terminal:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 4 ]; then
  echo "Incorrect number of input arguments: $0 $*"
  echo "Usage: $0 <login> <host> <username> <password>"
  echo "Example: $0 test 10.1.2.3 myuser mypassword"
  exit 1
fi

login=$1
host=$2
user=$3
pass=$4

unbuffer expect -c "
spawn mysql_config_editor set --login-path=$login --host=$host --user=$user --password
expect -nocase \"Enter password:\" {send \"$pass\r\"; interact}
"
```

Test it:

```
./mysql_config.sh login 10.1.2.3 myuser mypass < /dev/null
```

Answer (score 4):

The `--password` argument is designed to explicitly avoid passing a password on the command line, as this is considered bad security.

That being said, you could try to feed the password to `mysql_config_editor` anyway:

```
echo "$db_pwd" | mysql_config_editor set --login-path=local --host=localhost --user=username --password
```

(This may not work if mysql_config_editor insists on getting input from the current terminal instead of standard in; if that is the case, you don't have a way to provide the password from a variable).

As the answer you linked to states, you can use `mysql` directly to supply the password. Using `mysql_config_editor` is meant for storing the password in `.mylogin.cnf` in an encrypted form (i.e. you supply the password once from the terminal, it is then encrypted and saved in the config file, and mysql can use it from there).

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-config-editor.html

***Update***: You may be able to trick `mysql_config_editor` into thinking it is reading from an interactive terminal, by using the [`unbuffer` utility](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/unbuffer1.html):

```
echo "$db_pwd" | unbuffer -p mysql_config_editor set --login-path=local --host=localhost --user=username --password
```

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work. I am editing the question with other methods I have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this problem as well.
My solution was to run the command once, and supply the password on prompt

```
mysql_config_editor set --login-path=local --host=localhost --user=username --password
```

This generates the file .mylogin.cnf in users home directory.
Just copying this file (can be done from a bash script) to the user you want to give access using the --login-path option does the trick.

As I understand .mylogin.cnf  is just an obfuscated way of storing a username and password for that particular --login-path

Answer (score 0):

I needed to run the `mysql_config_edit` command in a Dockerfile in order to use them as arguments. I was able to do it by using printf:

```
printf '%s' "myPassword" | mysql_config_editor set --login-path=myconnection --host=connection.host.com --user=myconuser --password
```

It worked pretty well.