# How to run cron in a secure way? (getting this warning: "Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure")

Tags: php, security, cron

I've created a cronjob using cPanel.

Every a certain period of time it runs this php file that generates a backup:

```
<?php 
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'conectar.php';

$filename='backup_cursos_'.date('d-M-y__H:i:s').'.sql';

$result=exec('mysqldump '.DATABASE.' --password='.PASS.' --user='.USER.' --single-transaction >/home/cursos/backups/'.$filename,$output);

if($output==''){/* no output is good */}
else {/* we have something to log the output here*/}

?>
```

The constants `DATABASE`, `PASS` and `USER` are stored in `conectar.php` file.

I'm getting this warning message every time the cron runs:

> Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be
>   insecure.

I thought I was being secure adding the constants there, so my question is:

**How do I run the cron job in a secure way?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9293090/4621324

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Suppress warning messages using mysql from within Terminal, but password written in bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20751352/suppress-warning-messages-using-mysql-from-within-terminal-but-password-written) for details on that question. Basically: don't provide the password via command line but via settings.