# How to connect to mysql and to pass credentials on Jenkins freestyle job

Tags: mysql, jenkins, credentials

I am trying to connect to a remote MySQL Server from a Jenkins job.

I bound the MySQL user credentials into two variables `MYSQL_USERNAME` and `MYSQL_PASSWORD`. I need to SSH first, and then connect to MySQL. The shell command I used is:

`ssh remote_server mysql --user="$MYSQL_USERNAME" --password="$MYSQL_PASSWORD" -e "SHOW DATABASES;"`

(Build Step-> Execute shell)(quotes only for --user, --password and -e)

Summary of Error:
Using MySQL credentials on command line is insecure, and I get whole mysql help commands.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double quote the command you're executing remotely, and use single quotes around the parameters

```
ssh remote_server "mysql --user='$MYSQL_USERNAME' --password='$MYSQL_PASSWORD' -e 'SHOW DATABASES;' 2>/dev/null"
```

***2>/dev/null*** suppresses the warning, but there are definitely better ways to get around that, like not passing a password on the command line as it suggests.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. May I know what is recommended to connect to MySQL database server other than passing password as variable. I have used Credentials binding plugin and added the mysql user credentials on Jenkins global credentials. Using the quotes, worked and thank you.....:)

Comment: You're welcome, please mark it as correct if it is. Here's a discussion around the password warning, I'm sure there are plenty of others. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20751352/suppress-warning-messages-using-mysql-from-within-terminal-but-password-written