# Can't run mysql commands as root linux user

Tags: mysql, root, sudo

As linux root user:

`root@local:~# mysql`

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using
> password: NO)

I'm confused. Shouldn't the root user be able to run `mysql` without additional authentication? How do I fix this?

Comment: If you run just `mysql`  the root user should be without password

Comment: How about `mysql -u root -p`? Does it asked for password?

Comment: Of course it asks for a password if I specify a mysql user, but I don't want to provide a password, I want to run mysql commands as the linux root without a password.

Comment: Does [this](https://serverfault.com/a/563717/235281) or [this](https://serverfault.com/a/399274/235281) work for you?

Comment: Nope, those answers still require passwords in one way or another

Comment: It confuses a lot of Linux users that there is a Linux root user and a separate MySQL root user.  Your MySQL root user does not depend on the root account, after installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH auth_socket;`

Answer (score 0):

Your root account in MySql has a password. Try this

```
mysql -p
```

and enter the password you, or somebody set.

If that doesn't work try

```
mysql -h localhost -u root -p
```

It *that* doesn't work you'll need to reset your MySql root password. That's the topic of several tutorials on the 'toobz

Comment: `mysql -p` requires that the root linux account be able to run `mysql` without providing a password. Which is my problem.

Comment: @Dan your problem is that your root user has a password and you want to log in without one. That is not possible

Answer (score 0):

If the MySQL root user has a password, using the default authentication plugin, then you must provide a password to connect, full stop. You can configure an account with no password, but that's a habit you should avoid.

You can provide a password by any of the following means:

- Entering it interactively with the `-p` option
- Entering it in plaintext in the commandline like `-p<mypassword>`
- Storing it in plaintext in your `~/.my.cnf` file in the `[client]` section (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html)
- Storing it in an obfuscated form in your `~/.mylogin.cnf` file (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-config-editor.html).

There's also a way to provide a password through environment variables, but that's discouraged now because it's really not secure.

Comment: What about auth_socket?

Comment: That would work if you create the root user to be authenticated using the auth_socket plugin (example: `CREATE USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH auth_socket`), but if the root user were created in the conventional way, that is authenticated with a password, then auth_socket would not work.

Comment: I don't understand how the last server I set up had auth_socket set up by default and this new one doesn't. I'm trying to write an installation script to initialize a mysql database and I want to run mysql commands. I either need to use auth_socket (apparently not the default) or be able to provide the root password in the bash script (-p doesn't seem to work, it prompts for a password even if you provide a value).

Comment: Note that providing a password value on the command-line requires that you have no space between `-p` and the password. That is, `-p password` is wrong, it will interpret the password as the next argument. You must specify it like `-ppassword`.

Comment: I have no idea who set up your last server or what version it was. Perhaps it was MariaDB? MariaDB is not MySQL. They change a lot of features, and one of them is that the root user is created to use auth_socket by default, cf. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-plugins/

Comment: I don't know why it isn't a solution for you to use `.my.cnf` or `.mylogin.cnf`.

Comment: I generally try not to keep passwords in plaintext files, seems a little insecure to me. The `-p` comment was helpful though, thank you. Now I just have to decide between that and figuring out how to configure the mysql root user with auth_socket by default on/after installation in a scriptable manner. The MySQL server in both cases was installed with apt on Ubuntu 20 (so MySQL 8).

Comment: That's a strange choice, because recent versions of MySQL have started warning that using a password on the command-line is insecure. They recommend to put it in an options file (and be careful about the file permissions on that file). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20751352/suppress-warning-messages-using-mysql-from-within-terminal-but-password-written

Comment: I think my preferred way is using auth_socket style authentication then. I've read that it's the default used when installing MySQL but I must have done something to set the password and thus password-based authentication. Gotta figure out how to write my installation script properly so mysql creates the root user with auth_socket authentication.

Comment: Also - it's not technically "using a password on the command-line". It's using a password in a bash script where the password is assigned to a variable using `read -sp`. Is that still insecure?

Comment: You'll get the same warning from the mysql client, so yes, it's the same.